# Redirect ALL pages of site to page if using any IE browser - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, internet-explorer

I'm looking to redirect all traffic from IE to a page stating not to use IE for my Apache server. I have read a few articles and still do not understand how to implement. I even tried some i found here on Stack Overflow and cant seem to get it to work. Here is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE\*
RewriteRule (.*) IE.html
```

When ever i connect to the site with IE i dont get sent to the IE.html
Any Ideas?

Edit

I did some more research and it looks like i had some small mistakes. The code below now works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ IE.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and it looks like i had some small mistakes. The code below now works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ IE.html [NC,L]
```